# SAP UI5 : MultiCombobox selected values should appear in vertical fashion

Tags: sapui5

For my multicombobox, I need all the selected values to appear vertically rather than horizontally as it is hard to see all the selected values at once if there are more than 3-4 selections.

Comment: could you please tell us what u tried up to now?

Comment: Also, what about the height of the multicombobox when there are multiple selected values?

Answer (score 0):

With one of the latest releases of UI5, a "n-more" feature was introduced in the MultiComboBox. It could be seen [here](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MultiComboBox/preview). Add several items from the MCB and focus out.

I guess that this should be fine for you to see the selection no matter how much items you have at all. On the mobile view you can toggle the button next to the input field in the dialog in order to see all selected items.